# Видео из картинки - на каком языке проще сделать

Tags: c#, delphi, php, java, c++

Есть картинка

Нужно написать программу которая возьмет эту картинку и сделает видео, преимущественно на выходе mp4 длительностью 30 сек

т.е. получится видео у которого на фоне будет только картинка

на каком языке можно сделать и что юзать?

есть ли такя возможность у веб языков?

Comment: А что можете посоветовать по C# Java или Delphi?

ну не обязательно веб

лучше всего C# конечно для меня или Delphi на кройняк

задача немного усложнилась, нужно поверх видео еще текст намалевать
и формат видео может быть любым

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рекомендую посмотреть на [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/). Для c++, java есть обвязки. Для других можно просто ffmpeg.exe вызывать напрямую.

Answer (score 0):

Это у вас задача такая - написать такую программу, или вам нужен конечный результат - видео из картинок? Если второе, то лучше не изобретать велосипед и воспользоваться хотя бы и Movie Maker.

Comment: картинок несколько миллионов